# How can I join a table to another to do a select conditional upon a value in a column in the second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Exam Table and a query to get a list of exams:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exam] (
    [ExamId]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Exam] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ExamId] ASC)
);

SELECT   Exam.ExamId           AS ExamId,
         Exam.Title            AS Name
FROM     Exam
```

What I really need is for this query to be modified so that it only shows exams where there is also a test that has a TestStatusId = 3. I know I can just join these tables with a normal join but then I would get many exam rows for each test. All I need is to see the Exam.ExamId and Exam.Title of an exam with one or more tests with TestStatusID = 3.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [TestStatusId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [ExamId]       INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdminTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AdminTestId] ASC))
)
```

Can someone show me how I could join these two tables with a SELECT to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, I prefer to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT   E.ExamId   AS ExamId,
         E.Title    AS Name
FROM     Exam E
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AdminTest A
    WHERE A.ExamId = E.ExamId AND
          A.TestStatusID = 3)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `IN`:

```
SELECT   ExamId    AS ExamId,
         Title     AS Name
FROM     Exam 
WHERE ExamId IN (
    SELECT ExamId
    FROM AdminTest
    WHERE TestStatusId = 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` as the other answer shows, you can also add `TestStatusID = 3` to your `JOIN`:

```
SELECT   e.ExamId           AS ExamId,
         e.Title            AS Name
FROM     Exam e
JOIN     AdminTest a
  ON  e.ExamID = a.ExamID
  AND a.TestStatusId = 3
```

Or filter in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT   e.ExamId           AS ExamId,
         e.Title            AS Name
FROM     Exam e
JOIN     AdminTest a
  ON  e.ExamID = a.ExamID
WHERE a.TestStatusId = 3
```

Comment: The problem with the `join` is the OP wants the `distinct` results.  `Exists` should perform better than using `select distinct`.

Comment: @sgeddes Indeed `EXISTS` is typically the most efficient. `IN` can often be the least performant approach, makes sense to show them all, in my opinion.

Comment: I think current sql server engine optimizers actually treat `in` and `exists` the same, but I do prefer `exists`.  `select distinct` does quite a different operation though.  With that said, I agree showing all potential solutions is beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT     Exam.ExamId,
           Title AS Name
FROM       Exam
INNER JOIN AdminTest ON AdminTest.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
WHERE      TestStatusId = 3
```

You might also want to create a [foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx) on the AdminTest.ExamId column

Comment: The problem with the `join` is the OP wants the `distinct` results.  `Exists` should perform better than using `select distinct`.